# Change the class of a column from being a 'list' to... anything else

Tags: r

I've used the below to split a column (named 'Cabin') where the object contained letter/number, e.g. C23, D48, etc

```
library(stringr)

cabintest$Cabin1 <- str_extract_all(cabintest$Cabin, "[0-9]+")

cabintest$Cabin2 <- str_extract_all(cabintest$Cabin, "[aA-zZ]+")
```

The result was two columns:
Cabin1 with letters, e.g. 'C'
Cabin2 with numbers, e.g. '23'

However, all blank cells have filled with 'character(0)' and the columns have become lists.

How do I convert these back to data frames, or classes of columns that I can work with pls?

Comment: Have you tried `str_extract_all(cabintest$Cabin, "[0-9]+", simplify = TRUE)`?

Comment: The regex `"[aA-zZ]+"` is wrong, it should be `"[A-Za-z]+"` or, even better, `[[:alpha:]]+"`. (For digits, well, `"[[:digits:]]+"`.)

Comment: Also, I can't replicate your error using the examples you provided. If I use "C23", "D48" and "", the columns split into normal character vectors as desired. Perhaps show us a reproducible example including input data that reproduces the problem - otherwise it's difficult to see how anyone can help.